# Differences between IPV4 to IPV6 transition methods

Tags: networking, ipv6, ipv4

After some research, I found 3 main methods in order to establish the transition from IPV4 to IPV6,

1. Dual Stack
2. Tunneling
3. Translation

Now, I can understand them all and how they work, but very few resources explain when should one method be preferred over another one.

**So, what are the differences between the three which could lead to preferring one mechanism in particular?**

Obviously, real scenarios would be more than appreciated.

Comment: "Translation"? What do you mean by that? That's not, AFAIK, a known IPv6 transition method.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Translation makes use of NAT-PT or NAT64 in order to _translate_ IPV4 to IPV6 and vice-versa (thus the naming).

Comment: Hm. But those are not really in the same class as tunneling or native dual stack and aren't used for the same purposes. So I'm not sure how they got mixed in here. Were you reading something in particular? A book or web site?

Comment: @MichaelHampton That might be right, I'm far from being an expert in that matter. But pretty much any proposed google threads on "IPV4/IPV6 transition" includes it.

Comment: I can tell you what they all are, but that probably wouldn't be very useful. It might help write a better answer if you can also explain in your question what you understand of each of these technologies, and any ideas you might already have about how they would be used.

Comment: In the real world.  You are going to be doing dual-stack.  You may or may not need a tunnel IPv6 address space and routing.  You may try some translation, but that is mostly a huge mess that you should avoid or minimize.